# How to read list of data from Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building simple app using Firebase just to get a sense how to work with it.

Currently, I create notes using following approach

```
const notes = db.ref(`users/${user.uid}/notes`).push();
  notes.set({
   title, 
   description
});
```

But, how do I retrieve this list of data ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data

Comment: what should I look at ?

Comment: if you know exact answer to my problem you can post code below ;)

Comment: That page documents how to read/write lists of data, which seems to be what you're asking for. If you're having trouble getting the code in that documentation to work, please the [minimal code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I've read this docs and tried code you pointing me to and it doesn't solve my problem

Comment: I get that. But unfortunately that makes it hard to help: without seeing what you've tried and where you got stuck, it is unlikely we'll do a better job explaining how to read data from a list than the Firebase documentation.

Comment: what information do I need to provide to you? My guess is it that it should relatively straightforward. I just save data using code above and my next step is to retrieve saved data. 

What would be the simplest way to do this according to your experience or how would you do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach based on the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events):

```
const readUsersFromSnapshot = snapshot => {
  const users = [];
  snapshot.forEach(child => {
    users.push(child.val());
  });
  database.ref('users').off();
  return Promise.resolve(users);
};

const getUsers = () =>
  database
    .ref('users')
    .once('value')
    .then(readUsersFromSnapshot);

// getUsers().then(users => {
//     users array
// });
```